# how to show another activity from splash screen using OOP not thread

Tags: android, android-activity

here is my idea I want to create a component like activity in android so in this way I want to my main activity derived from my splash activity which is dervied from Activity and in my splash activity I want to check for a license and if it was available then I want to redirect to the main activity that has derived from splash activity.

My whole idea is having a component so by extending it from main activity everything should be automated.

I have done this use following code but it is not working smoothly and I'm sure there is something wrong with my approach:

```
//my main activity which will be shown after splash screen
public class MyActivity extends SplashLoader
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.setNextActivity(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText("hello");

    }
}

//my splash activity

public class SplashLoader extends Activity
{
    private static final String ERROR_MESSAGE = "Error message";
    private  Activity nextActivity=null;

    public Activity getNextActivity() {
        return nextActivity;
    }

    public void setNextActivity(Activity nextActivity) {
        this.nextActivity = nextActivity;
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout lLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        lLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        lLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
        lLayout.addView(iv);
        setContentView(lLayout);

boolean isRegistered = false;
        if(!isRegistered)
        {
            createDialog().show();
        }
        else
        {
        //    finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashLoader.this,getNextActivity().getClass());
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }



    private AlertDialog.Builder createDialog()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


        DialogInterface.OnClickListener clickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which)
            {
                switch (which)
                {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL:
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }
        } ;

        builder.setMessage(ERROR_MESSAGE).setNeutralButton("Ok" ,clickListener );
        return builder;
    }
}

//and my manifest 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Edit:

there isn't any error by this approach but after splash wants to load the mainActivity it has a lag or after changing the orientation I can see the mainActivity. the behaviour of this approach is a bit peculiar.

Comment: add the stack trace of the error , and  you should declare all your activities on your Manifest file , so if you have a second Activity that will be launched after the splash, you should declare both of activities : Splash and HomeActivity

Comment: there isn't any error by this approach but after splash wants to load the mainActivity it has a lag or after changing the orientation I can see the mainActivity. the behaviour of this approach is a bit peculiar.

Comment: why not just add a CountDownTimer, and display your SplashScreen for 4 seconds for example, and in onFinish() method of your timer, just do your test about license, and if test is OK , so launch the MainActivity via intent normally ??

Answer (score 0):

in `MainActivity.onCreate()` you are calling `super.onCreate()`. Because `MainActivity` derives from `SplashLoader` this will end up calling `SplashLoader.onCreate()`. In `SplashLoader.onCreate()` you inflate the view and call setContentView(). Then in `MainActivity.onCreate()` you do it again (thereby overwriting all the work you did in `SplashLoader.onCreate()`). Inflating views takes time (and resources) and this may be generating part of your visible delay. Also, `SplashLoader.onCreate()` calls startActivity() to start the `MainActivity` and this will be done again when `MainActivity.onCreate() calls super.onCreate()`.

If you really want to do something like extending `MainActivity` from `SplashLoader`, then you need to fix the way your lifecycle overrides work. You probably need to do something like this:

in **SplashLoader**:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    setNextActivity(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Do any activity-specific stuff
    doOncreate(savedInstanceState);
}

// Derived classes should NOT override onCreate(), but should
//  instead override doOnCreate() and put their activity-specific code there
protected void doOnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}
    // This is the SplashLoader-specific onCreate() stuff
    LinearLayout lLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    lLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ... etc etc etc ...
}
```

in **MainActivity**:

```
@Override
protected void doOnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // This is the MainActivity-specific onCreate() stuff
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setText("hello");
}
```